# Sql query compare and replace between different tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: Table "Components" and table "Something".

In both table there is a column "unit" and a column "code", for the same article the code is the same in both tables.

The two tables are coming from different environments and in many records the units have been written in a different way. I mean "kg - KG", "kilogram - kg".  Very messy!
I would like to run manually some query to adjust most of these differences.

```
  Components                        Something

  Code----Unit                     Code    Unit
   1      kg                        1       kilogram
   2      kg                        2       kg
   3      kg                        3       kilogram
```

In the above case the query should replace all "kilogram" in table "something" with kg". Something like replace in table "something" the unit value "kilogram" where in table components it is "kg" and the code is the same. 
I know what I wont but I do not know how to write it. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update Something 
   set Something.Unit = Components.Unit
  from Something 
  join Components 
    on Something.Code = Components.Code 
   and Components.Unit = 'kg'
   and Something.Unit  = 'kilogram'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `UPDATE JOIN`:

```
UPDATE Something
SET 
  Unit = S.Unit
FROM
Something S
JOIN
Components C ON
  (C.Code = S.Code)
```

This will set `Something.Unit` to the value of `Components.Unit`, using the code as a match.

**Note**: there's no need to check if the units are different, because the objective is to make them equal. Adding a `<>` clause would slow down the query, as no indexes would be used.